# jQuery Flot: reapeating labels on x-axis

Tags: jquery, flot

I'm trying to display month/year in my graph, but there is a bug with labels on x-axis:

[image]

**There is April 2012 3times** (and May and June).

Here is the code

```
function showGraph() {
        var data = [
            { label : "Odmeny", data: [ [(new Date('2012/04/01')).getTime(), 10], [(new Date('2012/05/01')).getTime(), 10], [(new Date('2012/06/01')).getTime(), 10] ] },
            { label : "Koeficienty", data: [ [(new Date('2012/04/01')).getTime(), 11], [(new Date('2012/05/01')).getTime(), 13], [(new Date('2012/06/01')).getTime(), 16], [(new Date('2012/07/01')).getTime(), 12] ] }
        ];
        var options = {
                xaxes: [{
                           mode: "time",
                           timeformat: "%b&nbsp;%y",
                           monthNames: ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "máj", "jún", "júl", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"]
                       }],
                       yaxes: [ {
                                  min: 0
                                } ],
                       series: {
                           lines: { 
                               show: true,
                               fill: null
                           },
                           points: {
                                show: true,
                                radius: 3,
                                lineWidth: 2,
                                fill: true,
                                fillColor: "#ffffff",
                                symbol: "circle"
                            }
                       },
                       grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true }
        };

        $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
    }
```

Comment: What version of Flot are you using?  Is it the Github master branch?

Comment: Well, there some information: Javascript plotting library for jQuery, v. 0.7., and Plugin for jQuery for working with colors, Version 1.1. ...no it's not the one from Github

Comment: Could you give the one from Github a try?  It's experimental, and breaks some things, but we've made a lot of improvements to time support; I'm wondering whether the problem you're seeing might be fixed. If you do try it, keep in mind that time support has been moved into a plugin, so you'll need to include that additional .js file.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it tomorrow and let you know

Comment: I have the lastest version and it's still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code (no minThickSize):

```
var options = {
            xaxes: [{
                       mode: "time",
                       timeformat: "%b&nbsp;%y",
                       monthNames: ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "máj", "jún", "júl", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"]
                   }],
                   yaxes: [ {
                              min: 0
                            } ],
                   series: {
                       lines: { 
                           show: true,
                           fill: null
                       },
                       points: {
                            show: true,
                            radius: 3,
                            lineWidth: 2,
                            fill: true,
                            fillColor: "#ffffff",
                            symbol: "circle"
                        }
                   },
                   grid: { hoverable: true, clickable: true }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Under xaxis options, set:

```
minTickSize = [1, "month"]
```

What's happening now is that Flot naturally tries to generate ticks more than once per month, which then appear as the same month due to your format string.

Comment: Sorry for late response, but it seems to be working now, I haven't changed anything. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
    lines: { show: true },
    points: { show: true },
    xaxis: { mode: "time", 
    timeformat: "%m/%y",   
    minTickSize: [1, "day"], 
    tickSize: [1, "month"]}
    };
```